# How to Open Files from MemoryStream in C#?

Tags: file, c#-4.0, memorystream

I have saved the files to database. These files may be of type Doc, PDF or Image. Now I'm trying to open these files from a DataGridView Cell_Click event using this code.

```
    private void dgvDocuments_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dgvDocuments.Columns[0].Index)
        {
            int id =Convert.ToInt32(dgvDocuments.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
            string query = "SELECT Photo FROM [dbo].[tblHR_Emloyee_Documents] WHERE ID = " + id;
            Utility.Generate_Window_Control.databaseFileRead(query);
        }
    }

    public static MemoryStream databaseFileRead(string query)
   {
       MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
       using (var varConnection = new SqlConnection(Utility.Global_Connection.conn))
       using (var sqlQuery = new SqlCommand(query, varConnection))
       {
           varConnection.Open();
           using (var sqlQueryResult = sqlQuery.ExecuteReader())
               if (sqlQueryResult != null)
               {
                   sqlQueryResult.Read();
                   var blob = new Byte[(sqlQueryResult.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
                   sqlQueryResult.GetBytes(0, 0, blob, 0, blob.Length);
                   //using (var fs = new MemoryStream(memoryStream, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
                   memoryStream.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
                   //}
               }
       }
       return memoryStream;
   }
```

During debug it shows me no error. Values are correct. But It is not opening the files. Kindly guide me how can I do this?

Comment: Where is your `DataGridView Cell_Click` code? How do you try to open file?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I have updated the code. I don't know how to open from a memory stream

Comment: Why you don't want to save it in the file then open?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I get the idea thanks

Comment: Add `memoryStream.Position = 0` so it starts reading again at the beginning.  Or use the MemoryStream(byte[]) constructor.